# Unit testing in RavenDB how to do it properly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, ravendb, nancy

So my problem is as follows...for a project we are bulding an api using RavenDb and Nancy. So my question is about unit testing...we use embeded db, which runs in memory as suggested many times. , how to proper unit test end points. For example, we have a endpoint create account. For that we need to have a user so he can create account. What is the best way to simulate that?

Currently we do it like this:

```
[Test]
public void UserCanAddAccountToCompany()
{
    var user =
      new User
      {
          Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
          Email = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
          Pwd = "password",
          CompanyReference = new CompanyReference { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
      };

    var response = new TestBrowser<User>("User/SignUp", user).Response;

    var paramUserAccount = new ParamUserAccount()
    {
        User = response.Body.DeserializeJson<Result>().User,
        Account = new Account() { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
    };

    var response2 = new TestBrowser<ParamUserAccount>("account/create", paramUserAccount).Response;
    var res = response2.Body.DeserializeJson<Result>();

    Assert.NotNull(res.Account.Id);
    Assert.NotNull(res.Account.Name);
}
```

So we create a user , call user signup end point and then take the params from response and call creat accoutn end point. The obvious problem with this approach is that if you do a change in signup endpoint and for some reason you break it, all tests like this will fail.

So my question is...what's the right approach on that?

Answer (score 0):

You are intergration testing, not unit testing. To properly unit test, you need to test without the db by using mocking objects.

Comment: Although you are right your answer is very compressed. Could you please guide the user how to do first steps in this direction or at least link to a similar question.